# Update a Google spreadsheet with a unique identifier

Tags: google-sheets

I want to update a google spreadsheet using a form. Each customer fills out the form with a unique identifier. This same identifier is entered in column A of each row.

I would like the other columns (B, C, ...) to be updated automatically according to the customer number.

Anyone have an idea for a script to use?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an `ARRAYFORMULA` together with `VLOOKUP`. You can see the documentation [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) and [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) respectively.

For example: `=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A1:A,'other_sheet!A1:C,2,0))`

This will add each value in A to each value in B like A1+B1, A2+B2, A3+B3, and so on.

If you post the formula you are trying to use, I may be able to adapt it using Arrayformula.